# Cannot password-protect Nginx subdirectory

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to set a *username/password* protection on an Nginx subdirectory, but I'm still able to access the subdirectory *without* supplying credentials.

The Nginx is running on an AWS CentOS 7 instance.
My `default.conf` is:

```
server {

    location /rbarak_test {
        satisfy any;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        auth_basic "Restricted area - This system is for the use of authorized users only!";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
}
```

I added a *username/password* entry to `.htpasswd`:

```
[centos@ip-172-31-35-133 nginx]$ ls -ls /etc/nginx/.htpasswd
4 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 45 Mar 24 23:39 /etc/nginx/.htpasswd
[centos@ip-172-31-35-133 nginx]$
```

And all the web-site files are at:

```
[centos@ip-172-31-35-133 nginx]$  ls /usr/share/nginx/html/rbarak_test/en/
amazon-dynamodb-audit-integration-guide.html  cockroachdb-integration-guide.html          jsonar--solutions-for-agentless-oracle-db-auditing.html  os-auditing-solution.html
amazon-redshift-audit-integration-guide.html  cockroach-integration-guide.html            mongodb-atlas-integration-guide-157488.html              params.manifest
aws-auditing-initial-setup.html               db-auditing-solution.html                   mongodb-atlas-integration-guide.html                     postgresql-integration-guides.html
aws-integration-guides.html                   dispatcher-rdbms-oracle-prerequisites.html  mongodb-integration-guides.html                          snowflake-integration-guide.html
aws-rds-audit-integration-guide-156347.html   glossary.html                               ms-sql-integration-guides.html                           sso-with-pingfederate.html
aws-rds-audit-integration-guide.html          image                                       mysql-integration-guides.html                            teradata-integration-guide.html
aws-rds-integration-guide.html                index-en.html                               oracle-audit-vault.html                                  toc-en.html
cloudera-integration-guides.html              js                                          oracle-integration-guides.html                           unified-auditing-solution.html
[centos@ip-172-31-35-133 nginx]$
```

But still, when I point my browser to `http://18.215.232.30/rbarak_test/?lang=en`, I'm not challenged to give a *username/password*.

Can you suggest what am I doing wrong?

Edit:
Typo in `location /rbarak_test` fixed. Still no challenge for credentials.

Comment: The spelling in the `location` and the URL are different.

Comment: Sharp eyes @Richard. Alas, even after the typo in `location /rbarak_test` was fixed, and `sudo nginx -s reload` executed, there's still no challenge for credentials.

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache?

Comment: I tested from an incognito window.